# AEM-when Page created the indicator light shows as published but they are not published

Tags: adobe, aem, publish

A newly created page in author displays information to the author that it has been published even thought the author has neither manually published the page.

Comment: What does appear in error.log or any other custom logs about the replication output?

Answer (score 0):

Check the page template, there is for sure a replication status & timestamp.

Comment: can you explain in details? I have used editable templates and template replication status is active.